# How can I hide others elements of my object that do NOT match my filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a filter in which I am looking at an object across a text field using the properties of title and name. if there are matches, the words are highlighted in yellow.

I would like to know how to do so that if there are coincidences the other elements of my object disappear showing only the object with coincidences.

[image]

this is my code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Lb56FtZxdIyMNluwCSm8?p=preview

```
  $scope.data = [{
    text: "<< ==== Put text to Search ===== >>"
  }];

  $scope.data = [{
    title: "Bad",
    name: 'bill'
  }, {
    title: "Good",
    name: 'Goe'
  }, {
    title: "Great",
    name: 'Brad'
  }, {
    title: "Cool",
    name: 'yan'
  }, {
    title: "Excellent",
    name: 'mikle'
  }, {
    title: "Awesome",
    name: 'mosa'
  }, {
    title: "Horrible",
    name: 'morteza'
  }];

})
.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
  return function(text, phrase) {
    if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('(' + phrase + ')', 'gi'),
      '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
  }

  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">  
  <ul>
    <!-- filter code -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
      <p><span>Title: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search"></span></p>
      <p><span>Name: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight:search"></span></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

thanks

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/gdtRTYzzzIHFvdqk60oI?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Filter the array by the search key, so only the matching objects will be displayed in the UI`ng-repeat="item in data | filter: search"`

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter: search">
  <p><span>Title: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search"></span></p>
  <p><span>Name: </span><span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight:search"></span></p>
</li>
```

Comment: additionally you can have `ng-repeat="item in data" ng-show="([item] | filter: search).length"` (helps with a potential one-way data-binding, where `filter` will not work)